# Flatlist of buttons does not render on first navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a Stack.Navigator, when I navigate to a page that contains my FlatList which renders 4x6 items at once, all of the other components will render and the flatlist will be invisible/not rendered. The app then locks up, and then after that the flatlist renders all the items and the layout is bumped around which is not desirable. Is this expected behaviour and what can I do about it? I'd prefer the whole app freeze/stutter until all of the first page is ready to show at once, rather than rendering everything but the Flatlist and then bumping the UI around.

The FlatList component is very uncontroversial as far as I can see.

```
      <View>
        <FlatList
          numColumns={4}
          columnWrapperStyle={styles.colWrap}
          keyExtractor={(theitem) => theitem.id}
          renderItem={renderIndividualSound(onSoundButtonPress)}
          data={soundPage}
          key="soundspage"
        />
      </View>
```

Comment: make a https://snack.expo.io/ or post all your code included styles

Comment: I will do when I've got a sec - but the styles are very simple flexbox styles, renderIndividualSound just returns a <Button> that uses the onSoundButtonPress in it's onPress prop.

Comment: Upon further inspection, I was using a useState() that init'd with a blank array, and then using a useEffect(, []) hook to update the state once at initialisation, meaning a blank list was passed through. Don't know how I didnt pick this up in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further inspection, I was using a useState() hook that init'd with a blank array, and then using a useEffect(()=>{}, []) hook to update the state once at initialisation, meaning a blank list was passed through for the very first render.